# How to restore globally reusable approval workflow?

Tags: restore, approval

I made changes in a globally reusable workflow (approval). How can I restore the OOTB workflow? I found some solution: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f54a9262-4fc8-41fd-86dc-de31dcaf216e/how-can-i-restore-global-reusable-approval-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
But which files should I change or restore in there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open the root site of the site collection in SharePoint designer.

Click AllFiles> _catalogs>wfpub.

All the global workflow are stored here.  You can open the Approval_SharePoint 2010 workflow and restore the files inside it to site definition.

For any workflows there will be the below set up of files :

- workflow name.xoml
- workflow name. xoml. rules
- workflow name. xoml. wfconfig.xml
- workflow name. xsn

Each files will have version history... by locating each file one by one, need to click on the version history.. then restore your desire version for the above files.

Note :

While restoring version of each files, make sure, you are restoring from same date and time for all the files otherwise workflow will be messed up.

Details steps are here :

[SharePoint Designer – Restore Previous Workflow Version](https://www.google.com/amp/s/wonderlaura.com/2012/05/02/sharepoint-designer-restore-previous-workflow-version/amp/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't restore previous version of the files. And I have the following files: https://ibb.co/fd6gRy6